# How do you assign a default value to a <functional> object?

Tags: c++11, c++17

I pass a function pointer to a function using functional, and use a constructor initialization to save it in a local variable for later use. How do I assign a default value to the parameter.

Example:

```
function<void()> BEGINFILE;
somefunct(function<void()> BEGINFILE): BEGINFILE(BEGINFILE) {}
```

But I can't seem to do:

```cpp
void nullfunct() {}
function<void()> BEGINFILE;
void somefunct(function<void()> BEGINFILE = nullfunct): BEGINFILE(BEGINFILE) {}
```

or:

```
void nullfunct() {}
function<void()> BEGINFILE;
somefunct(function<void()> BEGINFILE) {
   BEGINFILE = BEGINFILE;
}
```

I've also read that functional is deprecated/removed in C++17. I've tried to find what C++17 does without success.

Comment: I am quite sure std::function is not deprecated.   You can't use a constructor initializer unless the function is a constructor of a class.  In the last example `BEGINFILE` is a variable local to the function and shadows the global variable of the same name so `BEGINfILE = BEGINFILE;` assigns the function parameter to itself.  This works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/ryI1Uuam_

Comment: @Jerry Jeremia Thanks. this->BeginFile = BEGINFILE worked. What about optional parameters ```funct(function<void()>FUNCT = fun){}```

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - "In the last example BEGINFILE is a variable local to the function and shadows the global variable of the same name so BEGINfILE = BEGINFILE;" - Not exactly. If you see the exact names, you see there is a difference in the `f`: lower-case in the member name, upper case in the constructor argument name. Anyway, I consider this way dangerous, but `foo(int a) : a{a} { }` works as intended.

Comment: I completely missed making one letter in the middle of the name a different case.     Also, I said it shadowed the global variable because it wasn't obvious to me that it was a class - I thought these things were global declarations.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah thanks. Answers (1) and (2) from max66 seem to work. I corrected the code - thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `somefunct` is a `class` (or a `struct`) and that with

```
void somefunct(function<void()> BEGINFILE): BEGINfILE(BEGINFILE) {}
```

do you mean a constructor of `somefunct`.

First (secondary) problem: constructors doesn't return values, so remove the initial `void`.

For the main problem I suppose that you have the problem when the default function (`nullfunct()`) is a non static member function.

I mean, in this case

```
struct somefunct
 {
   void nullfunct() {}

   std::function<void()> bf;

   somefunct (std::function<void()> bf0 = nullfunct) : bf{bf0}
    { }
 };
```

Unfortunately, a non-static member function is something strange, very different from a regular function, and you can't assign it to a `std::function`.

I see three ways to solve this problem.

1. transform it in a `static` one

A `static` member function doesn't depend from an instance of the class so is the same type of object of a regular function and can be assigned to a `std::function`, so if you can transform `nullfunct()` in a static member, you can write

```
struct somefunct
 {
   static void nullfunct() {}

   std::function<void()> bf;

   somefunct (std::function<void()> bf0 = nullfunct) : bf{bf0}
    { }
 };
```

2. make `nullfunct()` an regular function.

If you can make `nullfunct()` a regular (not member of a class or struct) function, it becomes compatible with `std::function`, so

```
void nullfunct() {}

struct somefunct
 {
   std::function<void()> bf;

   somefunct (std::function<void()> bf0 = nullfunct) : bf{bf0}
    { }
 };
```

3. initialize with an empty function and set with a wrapping lambda

If you can't transform `somefunct()` in a `static` member function (way 1) or in regular function (way 2), you can wrap the call of `somefunct()` in a lambda function that you can assign to your `std::function`.

Unfortunately, this lambda function has to capture the `this` pointer and can't do it if is defined as a default value for the argument of the constructor so the way I see is initialize the `std::function` with an empty `std::function` and, in the body of the constructor, if the member contains an empty function, assign the lambda.

I mean

```
struct somefunct
 {
   void nullfunct() {}

   std::function<void()> bf;

   somefunct (std::function<void()> bf0 = {}) : bf{bf0}
    { if ( not bf ) bf = [this]{ this->nullfunct(); }; }
 };
```